# yii2 routing - pass parameter to route in rules

Tags: yii2, url-routing

When a user accesses `domain/page`, I need to route them to `controller/action/100`. 
I don't want to pass any parameter through the URL, but want to add it in url rules.

I added the code below to my config file.

```
'urlManager' => [
    'rules' => [
        'login' => 'site/login',  // working
        'about' => 'cms/page/10'  // Not Working
        'about' => 'cms/page?id=10'  // Not Working
    ],
],
```

The first rule is working fine.

Can I pass the parameter for the route in url rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [defaults](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlrule.html#$defaults-detail) and declare the rule explicitly:

```
'urlManager' => [            
    'rules' => [
        'login' => 'site/login',
        [
            'pattern'  => 'about', 
            'route'    => 'cms/page',
            'defaults' => ['id' => 10],
        ]  
    ],
],
```

Add `'mode' => \yii\web\UrlRule::PARSING_ONLY` to this rule if you want to prevent the transformation  when you create a URL with the UrlManager (e.g. `Url::to()` uses the UrlManager and its rules and works in the opposite direction, that is `Url::to(['cms/page', 'id' => 10])` will generate a link `about`)

Also consider to configure a redirect at your web server instead.