# Yii2 clean seo friendly url with parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, yii2

I'm using Yii2 for rebuild my codebase into Yii2. Everything working fine for me except url. I have many existing url already crawl on google so url should be same.

My Old url htaccess url:

```
RewriteRule ^cars/trustmark-cars-in-(.*)/page([0-9]+)$ cars.php?city=$1&tmcer=1&page=trustmark&pg=$2
RewriteRule ^cars/Make-(.*)/page([0-9]+)$ cars.php?make=$1&page=make&pg=$2
RewriteRule ^cars/(Petrol|Diesel)-(SUV|Two_Door)-cars/page([0-9]+)$  cars.php?fuel=$1&body=$2&page=fuel_body&pg=$3
```

In Yii2 main.php url rule:

```
'cars/<is_trustmark:(trustmark)>-cars-in-<city:(.*)>' => 'cars/index',
'cars/<make_name:(.*)>--<city:(.*)>' => 'cars/index',
'cars/<fuel_type:(Petrol|Diesel)>-<body_type:(SUV|Two_Door)>-cars' => 'cars/index',
```

Now i can't use the htaccess so how to make these kind of url.If i pass
cars/Make-Maruti then it should open a cars.php page with parameter make=1(Maruti id) so how to make these url rule.

Comment: have you tried with pretty url ?

Comment: yes i tried with pretty url but how to get the parameter as i expected for the url.

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/36887991/5658658

Comment: I need to genreate dynamic id based on url like... cars-in-Mumbai then Mumbai have some id = 10 then i need to fetch dynamic id based on url.

Comment: car/mycar.php is also not working.. ['pattern'=>'car/mycar','route'=>'controller/index',  'suffix'=>'.php'], but .html is working .. please help